# Why is $\emptyset$ symmetric and transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Take $A = \{0,1\}$. Now if we find all the subsets of binary relation i.e. $A\times A$ we get one of them as $R = \emptyset$. Now I can understand that $R$ does not have $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. So $R = \emptyset$ is not reflexive. But how is it symmetric and transitive?

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: What is $\phi$? What are you talking about?

Comment: ϕ is a relation on a non-empty set.

Comment: Do you by any change mean $\emptyset \subseteq X \times X$, the empty relation on a non-empty set $X$?

Comment: yup. Exactly. I mean that.

Comment: some relations are reflexive: you need to define the relation in order to know

Comment: Ahh, ok. For reference, the symbol for the empty set, while a bit like $\phi$, is not in fact a $\phi$ (if it was to be a letter, the danish letter Ø would probably be the closest contender). As to the question, it is just a matter of applying the definitions.

Comment: You can type the symbol for empty set as `$\emptyset$` $\emptyset$

Comment: And `\varnothing` makes it look correctly as $\varnothing $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's symmetric and transitive by a phenomenon called vacuous truth. Symmetricity and transitivity are both formulated as "Whenever you have **this**, you can say **that**". In the case of the trivially false relation, you never have "**this**", so the properties stand true, since there are no counterexamples.

Comment: So this means it is also irreflexive and antisymmetric. What about asymmetric? It should also be asymmetric because there are no counter examples. Isn't it interesting that R is both symmetric and asymmetric?

Comment: Yes, it is asymmetric as well. Both asymmetry and symmetry says something about what to expect when you have a pair of elements $a, b$ with $aRb$ true, and since there are no such pairs the properties hold. I find it easier to wrap your head around if you consider them something akin to promises. If the relation never breaks the promise that is called symmetry, then the relation is symmetric. And so on.